# AMD Drivers Kubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, ati, kubuntu

Using Kubuntu 15.10 kernel 4.2.0 generic 23 with AMD HD 4xx series GPU.

http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=Legacy2&os=Linux%20x86_64

Here says that this driver supports up to 3.4!(im kinda new to linux community,any help brothers?)

Answer (score 0):

There are no proprietary AMD drivers for this adapter that support modern Ubuntu releases.

The only option for this graphics adapter is to use open source driver.

Comment: By saying open source driver you mean...?

Comment: I mean just use the driver that is installed by default.

Comment: there is no default driver ( i think).im trying to run a game and fps drops from the start,i assume my gpu is not responding and the load goes to cpu thats why i have the frame drop

Comment: You are wrong. The adapter is just weak for modern games.

Comment: I've checked the minimum requirements needed to run the game and i've also played more heavy games with win7 in the past

Forgot to mention that not only the fps drops from the start but also the sound is bad(sounds like i have broken speakers).Maybe the iso is corrupted

Comment: Anyway there is nothing to be done in Ubuntu. You can use Windows for gaming.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to install such an old driver?

It would probably be better to open the KDE settings or search for "Additional drivers" and simply select the newest AMD proprietary/binary driver from the list. Ubuntu will then install it automatically and switch the open source driver to the proprietary one after rebooting.

I assume by "new to the linux community" you mean you're coming from Microsoft/Windows? Downloading and installing driver packages manually is not necessary nor would I recommend it if you do not know exactly what you are doing. You can let go of that Windows mentality and  use the built-in way mentioned above, instead.

Sincerely,
an Ubuntu sister. ;-)

Comment: Additional drivers cant detect anything except intel cpu and yes i was win7 user